# how to capture "this" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I even tried wrapping into a module but still failed to capture "this" on all attempts. The Javascript generated by the below Typescript doesn't resolve the **this** and it fails to return the desired result. How can i fix this issue in TypeScript?

```
var secretNumberGame = () => {
    var secretNumber: number = 21;
    var counter: number = 9;
    return {
        responses: {
            equal: "You are correct! Answer is " + secretNumber,
            lower: "Too high!",
            higher: "Too low!"
        },
        guess: (guess: number) => {
            counter++;
            var key = (guess == secretNumber) ? "equal" : (
                (guess < secretNumber ? "higher" : "lower"));
            console.log(this.responses[key]);
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
var game = secretNumberGame();
console.log(game.guess(45));
console.log(game.guess(18))
console.log(game.guess(21));
```

Comment: In ES6, arrow functions bind the "this" value. I don't know typescript, but maybe it's the same problem?

Comment: "*Typescript doesn't resolve the **this***". Do you mean it's undefined, or the global object?

Comment: This in this.responses doesn't resolve to return object's responses property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please just use a `function` and not `()=>`:

```
var secretNumberGame = () => {
    var secretNumber: number = 21;
    var counter: number = 9;
    return {
        responses: {
            equal: "You are correct! Answer is " + secretNumber,
            lower: "Too high!",
            higher: "Too low!"
        },
        guess: function (guess: number) {
            counter++;
            var key = (guess == secretNumber) ? "equal" : (
                (guess < secretNumber ? "higher" : "lower"));
            console.log(this.responses[key]);
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
var game = secretNumberGame();
console.log(game.guess(45));
console.log(game.guess(18))
console.log(game.guess(21));
```

Here are some docs on the fat arrow : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: another good source besides the one provided by basarat - http://piotrwalat.net/arrow-function-expressions-in-typescript/